# Making 'sudo pkg_add' work on NetBSD

Tags: netbsd, pkgsrc

Is there any way to make the simple command

```
sudo pkg_add some-package
```

work on an ordinary installation of NetBSD without recompiling anything from source code? All other Unix systems that I have tried provide an equivalent command out of the box with little effort.

The best I could think up was to add

```
export PKG_PATH="ftp://ftp.NetBSD.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/$(uname)/$(uname -m)/$(uname -r)/All/"
```

to `/root/.shrc` but sudo doesn't read `.shrc`.

The [pkgsrc FAQ, "Using 'sudo' with pkgsrc"](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/faq.html#using-sudo-with-pkgsrc) says that you can adapt the "just-in-time su(1) feature of pkgsrc" to use sudo but it requires editing a makefile and recompiling something. That seems like a steep requirement for such a basic task. Even without this modification, `pkg_add` doesn't ask me to `su` when I try to install packages as a normal user - it just says `pkg_add: Can't create pkgdb entry: /var/db/pkg/<...>: Permission denied`

OpenBSD has an [/etc/installurl](https://man.openbsd.org/installurl) file for this purpose but I couldn't find an equivalent one for NetBSD.

Comment: FWIW, in OpenBSD you can also allow `doas(1)` to not touch e.g. `PKG_PATH` and `TRUSTED_PKG_PATH` in the environment.

Comment: I think sudo's `env_keep` could also be used to preserve `PKG_PATH` but it seems simpler and safer to have a system-wide setting in the package manager's own configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right file is `/etc/pkg_install.conf`. To set it up, run this as root:

```
echo "PKG_PATH=ftp://ftp.NetBSD.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/$(uname)/$(uname -m)/$(uname -r)/All/" >> /etc/pkg_install.conf
```

See the [pkg_install.conf(5)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?pkg_install.conf) manual page for details about the file.

Note that the file has to be updated after each release upgrade. The release version number `$(uname -r)` will get stale.